# Showing different color markers on countries on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the following PHP function (mostly in Javascript) in order to show a some maps using the Google Maps Javascript API.

`$companyLocations` is an array with the adress and the latitud and longitud. For example:

```
$companyLocations = array(
            array('Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856),
            array('Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052),
            array('Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507),
            array('Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187),
            array('Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302)
        );
```

- `$width` is the width of the div.
- `$height` is the height of the div .

My code:

```
function showMap($companyLocations, $width, $height) {
    ?>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Show map with given height and width -->
        <div id="map" style="width:<?php echo $width?>;height:<?php echo $height?>;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          <?php
              // Convert the php array '$companyLocations' into Javascript array 'locations'
              $js_LocationsArray = json_encode($companyLocations);
           ?>
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });

              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              var marker, i;

              for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                    });

                    bounds.extend(marker.position);

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                                }
                              })(marker, i));
              }
              map.fitBounds(bounds);
                       </script>
       <?php
    }
```

**How can I show a different color marker for each country?** This means for example if some coordiates from the US, make the marker color red (for example) and I've some other cordinates from Mexico make the marker color blue.

This example has only two countries, but I can have up to N countries so I would need N colored markers.

Quick Photoshop to show my desired solution:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/8LkdWoQ.png]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this URL:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FFFFFF
```

It generates a marker that change its color depending on the hex code that you indicate. In this case it's `FFFFFF`.

So when you create the marker add the key `icon`with this value. In your case you could add a third element inside the locations array for the HEX code and then:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=•|' + locations[i][2]
});
```

You can also generate the HEX code randomly. Find more information here: [Random HEX codes in Javascript](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can set a custom icon or set a custom color, but how can I adapt this to my code so it can show a different HTML color for each country?

Comment: I have edited a bit the answer. You can add a third element to your array of countries with the color you desire for each one. Another alternative would be to generate the HEX code randomly, but in your case I would use the first alternative.